# Build a flex project on, ant or Maven?

Tags: apache-flex, jakarta-ee, actionscript, maven, ant

I am going to write a build commands for flex 4.5  project, which is only based on actionscript not with java. I am very new to both maven and ant.So can you people suggest which is more compatible and robust with Flex 4.5

Comment: Depends on your project difficulty, used libraries, dependencies. I'd suggest to use Ant, because it's easier to start with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven definitely has better integration with Flex than Ant. There are several reasons:

1. **Mature plugins**. Maven has especially great plugins for integration with Flex. The one that seems most matured and is in active development is [Flexmojos](http://flexmojos.sonatype.org/)
2. **Dependency management**. Maven can download libraries required by Flex on the fly. Maven embedded dependency management functionality is invaluable, especially for Flex projects.
3. **Generating project structure**. You can generate typical project to start from scratch using Maven. Personally I find it to be very useful and helpful.

Even though there are popular and supported bundle of readily available Ant tasks (called Flex Ant Tasks) available both with the open source Flex SDK and with Flash Builder (also I should point out that Ant might more also good choice if you're perplexed by Maven complexity or you need build automation for simple small-to-midsize project), Maven turns out to be more mature and more appropriate choice.

PS. You can find short manual on how to start with Maven for building Flex projects [here](http://www.mindtheflex.com/?p=55).